# Show that $Fix(ϕ)$ is ether {0}, a subgroup of the form $L = {tv : tR}$ for some $v ∈ R^2$ \ {0} or the full space $R^2$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

i have a problem:

> The fixed point set of $\varphi ∈ Aut(R^2)$ is defined to be
>
> $Fix(\varphi) = {v ∈ R^2: \varphi(v) = v}$
>
> Show that $Fix(\varphi)$ is ether {0}, a subgroup of the form $L =$ {$tv
>  : tR$} for some $v ∈ R^2$ \ {0} or the full space $R^2$
>
> Here $\varphi$ represents 2x2 matrices
>
> $$\varphi \begin{pmatrix}
>          x \\
>          y \\
>          \end{pmatrix} = 
>          \begin{pmatrix}
>          a & c \\
>          b & d \\
>          \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
>          x \\
>          y \\
>          \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
>          ax+cy \\
>          bx+dy \\
>          \end{pmatrix} $$

I have no idea how to prove that. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Show that $Fix(\varphi)$ is a vectorial subspace of $R^2$ then look at $dim(Fix(\varphi))$.